# Sorting Data in Reducer Actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to create a sort button which when clicked will sort me menu cards alphabetically. My question is **how should I have the sort function coded in the Reducer and Actions**? I added pseudo-code for sorting in the Reducer as well. When I click the button I am getting "(TypeError): state.slice is not a function".

**Edit:**
Added my button component and main Container.

Actions:

```
export const sortMenus = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOADING_MENUS" });
    fetch(`/api/menus`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(responseJSON => {
        dispatch({ type: "SORT_MENUS", cards: responseJSON });
      });
  };
};
```

Reducer:

```
export default function MenusReducer(
  state = {
    cards: [],
    loading: false
  },
  action
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOADING_MENUS":
      return {
        ...state
      };
    case "ADD_MENUS":
      return {
        ...state,
        cards: action.cards
      };
    case "SORT_MENUS":
      return state.slice().sort(function(menu1, menu2) {
        if (menu1.name < menu2.name) return -1;
        if (menu1.name < menu2.name) return 1;
        return 0;
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Button Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { sortMenus } from ".././actions/dataActions";

import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";

class SortButton extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super(); 
      this.state = { menus: [] };
    }

    handleMenuSort = e => {
        this.props.sortMenus()
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <Container>
            <Row>
              <div>
                  <button id="sort-button" title="Sort Menus" onClick= {this.handleMenuSort}>Sort Menus</button>
              </div>
            </Row>
        </Container>
        )
      }


    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
          menus: state.menus
        }
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        return {
            sortMenus: params => dispatch(sortMenus(params)),
        }
    };


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SortButton)
```

Container:

```
class MainContainer extends Component {

  displayCards = () => {
      switch(this.props.path) {
          case "menus":
              return (this.props.menus.cards.map(card => (
                  <NavLink style={{ color: "black" }} to={`/menus/${card.id}`} key={card.id}><MenuCard view={this.props.displayObject} info={card} /></NavLink>
              )));

          default:
              return (<div>Empty</div>)
      }
  };

  render() {
      return (
          <CardColumns>
              {this.displayCards()}
          </CardColumns>
        )
     }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return {
          menus: state.menus
      }
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
          displayObject: (id, category, type) => dispatch(displayObject(id, category, type)),
      }
  };

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MainContainer)
```

Comment: Why not just store it in state sorted? Or just store it in state and sort it on-demend when you want it sorted? What use case do you have where you sometimes want to randomly sort your state? Is the `sortMenus` function meant to fetch remote data or sort already fetched data in state?

Comment: @Drew I need to have a button handle the sorting for a challenge. The sortMenus function should fetch and sort the data.

Comment: Typically this would be two separate "actions", i.e. single responsibility principle, one "action" to fetch data and store it in your redux store and another "action" to sort it. Here "action" can be a literal action or it can just be a function. Is the task simply to have a function that fetches data and sort it? Is storing it in redux part of the challenge? What you have will certainly fetch and sort your cards, *so what really what is your question*?

Comment: I only need to make a button which will trigger the sorting of the menu cards. The thing is I am not really sure how to go about this in the most efficient manner. So I thought maybe I could make sortMenus do both. When I click the button I am getting "(TypeError): state.slice is not a function". I will post my button's component as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `state` is an object, not an array. You likely mean to sort the stored `cards` array.

`state.cards.slice(...` instead of `state.slice(...`

```
case "SORT_MENUS":
  return state.cards.slice().sort(function(menu1, menu2) {
    if (menu1.name < menu2.name) return -1;
    if (menu1.name < menu2.name) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
```

Side note: You may also want to clear/set your `loading` state upon successful data fetching. ;)

**EDIT**

You are mapping undefined state within `mapStateToProps`, then mapping over it in the component. Change `mapStateToProps` to access the correct defined property.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  cards: state.cards,
});
```

Then you can iterate over the new `cards` prop.

```
case "menus":
  return (this.props.cards.map(card => (
    <NavLink
      style={{ color: "black" }}
      to={`/menus/${card.id}`}
      key={card.id}
    >
      <MenuCard view={this.props.displayObject} info={card} />
    </NavLink>
  )));
```

Comment: Fixed that but now I am getting "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" when clicking the button. Seems to be because it needs to map through all the menus again. My map is in the displayCards function in the main container. I will edit post to show how it looks

Comment: What is `state.menus` in `mapStateToProps`? There is only `cards` and `loading` in your redux state.

Comment: Its mapping the cards based on the menus since I have a menu card component. If I change "this.props.menus.cards.map" to "this.props.cards.map" in the container's case, I get "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" in /menus.

Comment: Where does `state.menus` come from? It isn't in your redux store (that you've shared). This is turning into a rabbit hole if fixing/addressing one issue uncovers another.

Comment: Seems that it is wrong in the button component. I was thinking, is it possible to make the button inside the main container instead of as a separate component?

Comment: @JabbatheHutt You don't do anything with `this.props.menus` nor map anything in your button component.

Comment: How should I implement the map for the button component? Could you show syntax wise?

Comment: @JabbatheHutt There is no issue with the mapping syntax, the issue lies with _what_ you're trying to map, it doesn't exist in `Container`. What are you trying to map?

Comment: I need to map through all the menu cards. Then sort them when button is clicked.

Comment: You should either pick `menus` or `cards` as a name and be consistent. In state you have `cards`, but in your `Container` component you map undefined state `state.menus` to a prop `menus`, *then* you try mapping `this.props.menus.cards` which OFC fails.

Comment: In Container mapping "this.props.menus.cards.map" is how the menus are displayed normally unsorted. If I do "this.props.cards" its undefined. For "this.props.teams.map" its not a function error.

Comment: @JabbatheHutt Instead of this back and forth about what I'm trying to explain is undefined because it isn't in your redux state, can you create a codesandbox (or similar) of your app (a working demo would be great)? Debugging would go much more quickly. In the meantime, has my answer about the current issue with sorting been resolved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209199/discussion-between-jabba-the-hutt-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store the fetched menu in application state.
You can have standalone action say SORT_MENU_BY_ALPHABET.
You can simply dispatch this action on button handler as well as on Ajax success. this dispatch may not have any payload associated.

hope it helps.

Comment: export const sortMenus = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOADING_MENUS" });
    fetch(`/api/menus`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(responseJSON => {
        dispatch({ type: "ADD_MENUS", cards: responseJSON }); // dispatch your sort menu by alphabet here after this line
      });
  };
};

Comment: I meant the dispatch for the sort. How should the sorting look like in the action?

Answer (score 0):

in reducer you defined state as object and you're trying to do array operation on it. `state.slice()`.
slice is a function available for arrays. so its throwing error.
you should be doing

`state.cards.slice().sort((a,b)=> a-b)`